# ContourPlot fails to plot a simple triginometric function squared

Tags: plotting

The two plots should be exactly the same in the following. However, the one squared gives nothing. I tried `MaxRecursion`, `PlotPoints`, etc. but not helpful. Is there any workaround?

```
d1 = -(Cos[x] + Cos[z] - Cos[2.5] - 2); d2 = 0;
ContourPlot[d1 == 0, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {z, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
ContourPlot[d1^2 == 0, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {z, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: it is simply because there are no values which is zero for the second case. Hence nothing to draw. `d1 = -(Cos[x] + Cos[z] - Cos[2.5] - 2); d2 = 0;
Table[(d1^2 /. {x -> x0, z -> z0}) == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi, Pi/10}, {z, -Pi,
   Pi, Pi/10}]`  gives all `False`

Comment: As stated on "Possible Issues" section of `ContourPlot` documentation: "Contours of $f(x, y) = 0$ of functions $f(x, y) \ge 0$ are poorly detected."

Comment: According to the document of `ContourPlot3D`, "For functions that are always non-negative, it is not possible to find the 0 contour:"

Comment: Also, this is a side effect of general contour-finding algorithms which basically assume contours can be found only in locations which are (on possibly subdivided) grids between grid points of which one is greater and another smaller than the contour value being searched. With real-valued function squared and contour value of zero it's naturally impossible to find these contours reliably.

Comment: The real trick (per @cvgmt's removed comment) here appears to be triggering a simplification which converts the equation back into $cos(x) + cos(z) = c$ form, which again has clear contour crossings (unless $c = \pm 2$, when solutions are individual points). I don't believe such trivial transformations exist in general, though.

Comment: @kirma The info about the general algorithm is very helpful. Thanks.